# Django template inheritance delivers no css?

Tags: python, django

In my django project there are some mysterious (at least for me as a beinner) outputs I don't understand while working in my development environment.
I wanted to have a base template which includes a stylesheet in a static media folder...this works so far...but just for the address http://localhost/ all the other urls have a template which inherits from the base template.

Now the stylesheet of http://localhost/ looks nice...if i go to http://localhost/hello/ the included stylesheet has a whole html DOM structure with body, doctype etc. why is that? He somehow parses a html site instead of taking the css file...

Here my code: Any ideas?

urls.py:

```
from django.views.static import * 
from django.conf import settings
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^$',home_view),
    ('^hello/$', hello),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ('^useragent/$',ua_display_good1),
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', 
)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def hello(request):  
    pagetitle = "Hello World"
    return render_to_response('hello.tpl', {'pagetitle': pagetitle})

def home_view(request):
    pagetitle = "Something"
    return render_to_response('home.tpl', {'pagetitle': pagetitle})

def ua_display_good1(request):
    try:
        ua = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    except KeyError:
        ua = 'unknown'
    return render_to_response('base.tpl',{'ageone': ua})
```

base template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<meta name="description=" content="{{metadescription}}">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/style.css">

<title>{% block title %}{{pagetitle}}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{% block h1 %}{{ageone}}{% endblock %}</h1>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}{% include "footer.tpl" %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

hello template:

```
{% extends "base.tpl" %}
{% block h1 %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block content %}Welcome{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have set the link to css as relative `"media/style.css"`. In home it resolves to `"/media/style.css"` but in hello it resolves to `"/hello/media/style.css"` (which gives the hello page).

Just use absolute css link like this: `"/media/style.css"`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because you have a relative reference to the CSS file.

Try changing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/style.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/style.css">
```

so it always look in the root for media/style.css

Comment: that's it! But i don't understand the problem...with the root slash he gets the data and without just displays it? Tanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to include the style sheets would be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

if this still wont work ....my css file name is Stylesheet.css and i linked it as  `css/Stylesheet.css` ..it wasnt working... then i changed it to `css/Stylesheet.CSS` ..and it worked

Answer (score -1):

Change href="media/style.css" to href="media/style.CSS" and it will work.